# Difference between closeEditorsAndGroup and closeEditorsInGroup

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the difference between these two command IDs in VSCode?

- `workbench.action`.**closeEditorsAndGroup**
- `workbench.action`.**closeEditorsInGroup**

Both seem to trigger the same action when I run it (they both close all editors in the current editor group and the editor group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the same behaviour because you must have :

`workbench.editor.closeEmptyGroups` set to **true** in your settings - that is the **default**.

> Controls the behavior of empty editor group when the last tab in the
>   group is closed.  When enabled, empty groups will automatically close.
>   When disabled, empty groups will remain part of the grid.

So you would see a difference if that was set to `false` (unchecked).